# Can I add bundles to a Symfony 4 project that doesn't have a recipe for flex?

Tags: php, symfony, recipe, bundles

Is it possible to add bundles in Symfony 4 that doesn't have a flex recipe?

I would like to add the following bundle

https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors

to my symfony 4.0 project, but it doesn't have a recipe (https://flex.symfony.com/) available. So when I install it with composer and add the config to my services it complains that it doesn't know the bundle.

Comment: [Using Symfony Flex to Manage Symfony Applications](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role of a flex recipe is to automate registration of bundles in kernel, adding configuration stubs, and so on. If a bundle doesn't have a recipe, and you were able to install it with composer (which means that the package constraints allow Symfony 4) you have to configure the bundle manually, starting with adding the bundle to `config/bundles.php`:

```
return [
    // ...
    Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Bundle\DoctrineBehaviorsBundle::class => ['all' => true]
];
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was searching for the appkernel to add the bundle there.

Comment: It's now `\App\Kernel` by default. It still has `registerBundles` method, so you could add your bundles there, but in version 4 they moved it to `config/bundles.php`, which is simply included in that method.